# How can I print a (void **) data in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack, void-pointers

I'm having a hard time fully understanding and learning the behavior of pointers, casts, and all that.

I have the following struct, which is basically a `stack data structure`:

```
struct stack
{
    void **items;
    size_t top;      
    size_t max_size;
};
```

I want to be able to return the `top element`, so this is my `Peek` function:

```
void *Peek(const stack_ty *stack)
{
    return(stack->items[stack->top]);
}
```

And this is my testing print in `main.c`:

```
stack_ty *new_stack = CreateStack(5);
 
Push(new_stack, (void *)1);
Push(new_stack, (void *)2);
Push(new_stack, (void *)3);
 
printf("The top element is %d\n", *(int *)Peek(new_stack));
```

I'm getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` right after it enters the `Peek` function.

I can guess it is related to the `*(int *)` cast I did to the return value of `Peek()`, but I can't think about any other way to `print()` or show any value that is passed by `void *`. I mean, I have to cast it to `int *` or `char *` or whatever, right?

What am I doing wrong here? I'll be glad to hear any tips on how to better understand this whole `pointers` thing. I mean, I thought I was pretty good at it, but I guess I was wrong.

To be honest, in the beginning I thought I needed to cast `1,2 and 3` to `(void *)&1`, `(void *)&2`, `(void *)&3`, because I thought I can't pass them just like that, and I thought that if I want to cast an `int` to a `void *` I have to give it the `address` of the `int`.

But the compiler screamed at me, so I changed it to `Push(new_stack, (void *)3);`

Comment: The answer to this question is highly dependent on the implementation of the functions CreateStack and Push and I wonder why you didn't include that code with your question.  Given what you've posted no one likely will be able to help.

Comment: @JJF not in this case. The bug is actually clearly in the code that is posted here.

Comment: `(void *)1` result sin "the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation".  It may not round-trip back to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're casting an `int` to a `void *` when you push, you need to cast it back to an `int` when you peek, not to an `int *`. You're not storing a pointer to an integer in the stack, you're treating the integer itself as if it were a pointer.

```c
printf("The top element is %d\n", (int)Peek(new_stack));
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Can you explain me a little bit on why don't we need to assign the `address` of those `ints` when we cast them to `void *`? I mean with `(void *)&3` for example? Because a `pointer`'s value is an address.. so I would guess we need to assign him an address as we always do when we declare and define a new pointer.

Comment: `(void *)3` doesn't have the address of anything. If you try to dereference it, you're looking for an integer at memory location 3.

Comment: @NoobCoder A pointer's value is _supposed_ to be an address, but `(void *)3` just crams a 3 into it anyway.  Now you have a `void*` whose value is 3, rather than the address of something.  You have to do the opposite cast to get the value out that you used to cram the value in: Since you started by casting an `int` to a `void*`, the inverse is to cast the `void*` to an `int`.

Comment: @Barmar that's my point! That when I write `(void *)3` I don't really cast the integer `3` from `int` to `void *`, i'm casting the memory location, the address `3` to be pointed by this `void *`. Should I write something else instead of `(void *)3` when I want to pass it to the `Push` function that receives a `void * element` and a `stack*` ?

Comment: You could declare a variable `int foo = 3;` and the `Push(new_stack, (void *)&foo)`